# Exception in thread main: Unable to locate an element with the x path expression

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver with Java to automate a page. The problem I'm facing  is that my test can't recognize any element on the page.

For example i'm trying to click button called `LogIn` and i tried by `xpath`, `id`, `css` selector but neither one of these option worked for me.

This is html code:

```
<button type="button" id="ext-gen72" class=" x-btn-text tdgi_icon_key">LogIn</button>
```

This is my code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\mkrolo\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("page");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(13000);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("button[contains(text(), 'LogIn']"));
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//@button[text()='LogIn']")).click();
   }    
}
```

**Additional comments:** this is just one example i tried in order to click the button, and also `Thread.sleep()` because it takes long time to load the page.

I appreciate every help you can provide.

Comment: Can you share your DOM snippet becausethere is error in your x path syntax. it should be driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='LogIn']")).click(); or By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'LogIn']")

Comment: mean it missing root selector or  the `//`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using invalid `xpath`. Try

```
By.xpath("//button[contains(., 'LogIn']")
```

Comment: Hi tnx for info, i tried it that way also and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @mirx Check if the button is inside `<iframe>` tag. You can also try `"//button[contains(., 'LogIn']"`

Comment: @mirx Try `driver.switchtTo().frame("mainPanel");`

Comment: I got this error message: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id mainPanel . It is strange to me because i practiced this stuff on many different websites and only this one gives me problems.

Comment: @mirx Is there another frame? can you share the link?

Comment: @mirx It does, you need to switch to all the frames in the hierarchy. Switching to frame changes the driver context to this frame. You can't switch to a frame inside another frame as you can't click on anything inside it without switching to it first.

Comment: Oh okay, tnx for helping. :) Ill do more research on how to move hierachichlly through frames and hopefully find solution. I will just remove few comments where i put code because im not sure if I can share that amount of our code.

Comment: @mirx You just need to switch to them one by one. Switch to the first one and then to the `mainPanel` frame.

Answer (score 1):

Both of xpath, you are using are not valid. This is the cause of exception. So you have to try with valid xpath or some other locator-

**xpath**

- `//button[contains(text(), 'LogIn']` - this will locate the button if partial text match
- `//button[text()='LogIn']` - this will locate the button if full text match if there are space before or after the text then it doesn't work
- `//button[@type='button'][@class='x-btn-text tdgi_icon_key']`

**css**

- `.x-btn-text.tdgi_icon_key` e.g. `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".x-btn-text.tdgi_icon_key"));`
- `button[type='button'][id^='ext-gen']`

You have to explore some tutorial for better customized xpath and css creation.

Additionally, avoid using hard coded wait in script instead, use selenium implicit and explicit wait concepts.

Comment: Hi tnx for the tips and corrections, however even when I change all the stuff it gives me the same error. In answer above yours i commented that there is an iframe but after trying driver.switchTo().frame(mainPanel); it gives me error that it cant locate frame.

Comment: @mirx, that means you are switching into wrong iframe, make sure you are locating correct iframe,

Answer (score 0):

To aid you with xPath and avoid errors like this, you can Inspect and copy xPath using Chrome and enter the same value in selenium selector.

[image]